# Can BLE peripheral know if somebody is connecting?

Tags: objective-c, macos, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any way to know (being BLE peripheral device) if somebody is connecting, connected or reading your characteristics? Can not find anything similar in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013015-CH1-SW20).

Comment: Yeah sure. An event is typically fired once a Central device performs a BLE operation on your peripheral device.

Comment: @OsmanEsen, could you please provide me with the link to the documentation? What is the name of event?

Comment: @LA_: in didSubscribeToCharacteristic you can get call back when some service is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` don't expose any method so as to notify the `CBPeripheralManager` that a `CBCentral` has been connected to it.

You can figure out if a Central is connected using the `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` function :

```
didSubscribeToCharacteristic
```

This will tell you for sure that there is a Central connected to your Peripheral.

Moreover, you can use the equivalent `didUnsubscribeFromCharacteristic` to assume that a Central has been disconnected.

Bottom lines, there is no way to get notified when you receive the connection.